# Is HTTP response always in HTML?

Tags: html, http

Is the HTTP response always in HTML? When a mobile application, uses HTTP to interact with back-end server and seeks some data in response, what is the format of that data? is it always in HTML?

Comment: Not at all, people can send any kind of data over HTTP: popular ones are JSON, JavaScript, XML,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not! HTTP is just a protocol to transfer an amount of data from the server to the client.

It's up to the client to decide what to do with the data. If you want, it can be a JSON, XML, HTML or just plain text. That's why you can have a look at the source of a webpage. In that case the webbrowser shows you (almost) the raw data which the server sent.

It's up to you how you want to handle it. As an HTML Syntaxed text, a Plain text, binary, or whatever you can imagine.